# Does Tasklet's action function run with Interrupt on?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am trying to find out about the context in which Tasklet's action function (that has been set in tasklet_init) runs ?

```
static void tasklet_action(struct softirq_action *a)
{

    struct tasklet_struct *list;

    local_irq_disable();
    list = __this_cpu_read(tasklet_vec.head);
    __this_cpu_write(tasklet_vec.head, NULL);
    __this_cpu_write(tasklet_vec.tail, this_cpu_ptr(&tasklet_vec.head));
    local_irq_enable();

    while (list) {
    if (tasklet_trylock(t)) {
        t->func(t->data);
        tasklet_unlock(t);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Above function suggests that before Tasklet's action function runs, Interrupts are enabled.

1. Does it mean action function(deferred functions) runs in process context or we haven't completely returned from Interrupt (we are on the way out after drivers interrupt handler) and thus deferred functions runs in interrupt context ?
2. Usually, tasklet_schedule is called from inside driver's interrupt handler( that runs with Interrupts disable) but then why again there is a need to disable interrupt again ?

   ```
   void __tasklet_schedule(struct tasklet_struct *t)
   {

       unsigned long flags;

       local_irq_save(flags);---> Interrupts is disabled again ?
       t->next = NULL;
       *__this_cpu_read(tasklet_vec.tail) = t;
       __this_cpu_write(tasklet_vec.tail, &(t->next));
       raise_softirq_irqoff(TASKLET_SOFTIRQ);
       local_irq_restore(flags);

    }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, answers will depend on the Linux version.  *tasklet* and others are an internal Linux API and can change from version to version.

---

> Does it mean action function(deferred functions) runs in process context or we haven't completely returned from Interrupt (we are on the way out after drivers interrupt handler) and thus deferred functions runs in interrupt context?

*Interrupt context* is special and runs in the memory space/context of the interrupted task.  A *tasklet* runs in a kernel process with no user memory mapped; but it is in super mode.  You can call more kernel functions here as kernel objects will be allocated on behalf of the kernel process and not some random user process.  How the *tasklet* is run is probably dependant on the Linux version, but a context switch will definitely happen.  Usually the kernel process is marked as **runnable** and the interrupt returns.  This *tasklet* (kernel process) can normally be interrupted of course.

> Usually, tasklet_schedule is called from inside driver's interrupt handler( that runs with Interrupts disable) but then why again there is a need to disable interrupt again ?

Interrupts can be pre-emptable/prioritized..  Ie, a higher level interrupt may interrupt another.  Also, the `tasklet_schedule()` can be called from **more** than interrupt context.  Ie, some kickstart initialization or some such?

This question appears to be a code critique?  It might be possible to make a `tasklet_schedule()` where interrupts are assumed disabled.  However, it would be error prone and the code to save interrupts is minimal.  I think either is possible so *why* is a difficult question.

Comment: `on behave of` -> `on behalf of`

Comment: Thanks @artless noise for your answer, some how I just missed it.I can say softirq runs with I bit of CPSR cleared (means core can react to Interrupts) whereas while scheduling softirq's I bit of CPSR must be set(means core can't react to Interrupts). Also while executing softirq's we may or may not disable interrupts that depends on what we do inside softirq handler

Comment: Also, lets Linux running on multi core SMP system , there comes an interrupt and taken by one of the core , On this core IRQ line from CPU to GIC is masked and Interrupt handler(Scheduling softirq in handler) start executing but at same there comes an other interrupt , taken by other core (earlier core can't react to it) and would other core  also start executing same interrupt handler? or interrupt handler should be protected by lock ?

Comment: Races with the GIC are a separate question.  When the interrupt source is read a 2nd time by another core it will return a `spurious` value.  The GIC takes care of this multi-core race; it will only return the current interrupt to one core.

Comment: @artlessnoise, It means same Interrupt handler(ISR) can't be run on multiple cores, right ? Also one doubt bothering me, If ISR's are run with interrupt disabled then, do we at all need to use any of the spin_lock variant to protect shared data inside ISR?

Comment: why we need to have spin_lock https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-sprat-3.10-kitkat-wear/arch/powerpc/sysdev/pmi.c#60 to protect shared data inside ISR ?

Comment: You disable interrupt on one core at a time.  You need a `spin_lock` to protect mainline code.  An ISR can be interrupted in some configurations.  Usually the ISR is locked to one core (at least in some versions of Linux) so that it's cache is more effective.  It can migrate to different cores.  `spin_lock` can still be used incorrectly.  There is not a generic issue though and they might be needed.  You need to look at the driver structure.